# Oracle FIRST_ROWS optimizer hint

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I'm writing a query against what is currently a small table in development. In production, we expect it to grow quite large over the life of the table (the primary key is a number(10)).

My query does a selection for the top N rows of my table, filtered by specific criteria and ordered by date ascending. Essentially, we're assigning records, in bulk, to a specific user for processing. In my case, N will only be 10, 20, or 30.

I'm currently selecting my primary keys inside a subselect, using rownum to limit my results, like so:

```
SELECT log_number FROM (
  SELECT
    il2.log_number,
    il2.final_date
  FROM log il2
  INNER JOIN agent A ON A.agent_id = il2.agent_id
  INNER JOIN activity lat ON il2.activity_id = lat.activity_id
  WHERE (p_criteria1 IS NULL OR A.criteria1 = p_criteria1)
  WHERE lat.criteria2 = p_criteria2
  AND lat.criteria3 = p_criteria3
  AND il2.criteria3 = p_criteria4
  AND il2.current_user IS NULL
  GROUP BY il2.log_number, il2.final_date
  ORDER BY il2.final_date ASC)
WHERE ROWNUM <= p_how_many;
```

Although I have a stopkey due to the rownum, I'm wondering if using an Oracle hint here (`/*+ FIRST_ROWS(p_how_many) */`) on the inner select will affect the query plan in the future. I'd like to know more about what the database does when this hint is specified; does it actually make a difference if you have to order the table? (Seems like it wouldn't.) Or does it only affect the select portion, after the access and join parts?

Looking at the explain plan now doesn't get me much as the table hasn't grown yet.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Even with an ORDER BY, different execution plans could be selected when you limit the number of rows returned.  It can be easier to select the top n rows by some order key, then sort those, than to sort the entire table then select the top n rows.

However, the GROUP BY is likely to restrict the benefit of this sort of optimization.  Grouping (or a DISTINCT operation) generally prevents the optimizer from using a plan that can pipe individual rows into a STOPKEY operation.

Comment: Don't you have to sort the entire table if you're asking for an order by? Unless your write order maps to the keyed column? That said, you mentioned the term 'pipe'. Do are all oracle internal functions pipelined? Streaming would make a difference.

Comment: For the first question, see http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2006/06-sep/o56asktom-086197.html.  From the section on Top-N queries: "ROWNUM has a top- N optimization that facilitates this type of query. You can use ROWNUM to avoid a massive sort of large sets.".  It's the same thing you'd do (I hope) if I gave you a large pile of numbered cards and asked you to find the 10 highest numbers.

Comment: For the second question, I take "Oracle internal functions" to mean operations in an execution plan.  Some of these - such as NESTED LOOPS and HASH JOIN - are capable of "streaming" as you call it - returning individual rows as they are selected, rather than having to completely process all rows before returning any.  Other operations are not; I believe that any grouping operation (such as SORT GROUP BY or HASH GROUP BY) would fall into this category.